# Post Error 500 adding a new row using Eloquent

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to follow a tutorial making a social network, the functionality of liking and disliking when no row is available in the database using Ajax (adding a new entry) is broken.
 Tutorial i'm following - this video is where he creates the controller: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drM19VKbCgU&list=PL55RiY5tL51oloSGk5XdO2MGjPqc0BxGV&index=20

Development Enviroment:

- PhpStorm v9.0
- Xampp v3.2.2
- jQuery v1.12.0
- Google Chrome

Error image:
[Error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8uT2.png)

The Whole cycle:
Like and Dislike Button (The View):

```
<a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ?
Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 1 ?
'You like this post':'Like' : 'Like' }}</a> |

<a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ?
 Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 0 ?    
'You don\'t like this post':'Dislike' : 'Dislike' }}</a>

<script>
    var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
</script>
```

route:

```
Route::post('/like', [
   'uses' => 'PostController@postLikePost',
    'as' => 'like'
]);
```

listener + Ajax Call:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;

//console.log(postId+' '+isLike);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlLike,
    data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
})
    .done(function(){
        console.log(event.target.innerText);
        event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this post':'Like' : event.target.innerText == 'Dislike' ? 'You don\'t like this post':'Dislike' ;
        if(isLike){
            event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Dislike';
        } else{
            event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Like';
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function postLikePost(Request $request){

    $post_id = $request['postId'];
    $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true';
    $update = false;
    $post = Post::find($post_id);
    if(!$post){
        return null;
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id', $post_id)->first();

    if($like){
        $already_like = $like->like;
        $update = true;
        if($already_like == $is_like){
            $like->delete();
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        $like->like = $is_like;
        $like->post_id = $post_id;
        $like->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    // This is working when the controller is updating but broken when saving

    if($update){
        $like->update();
    } else{
        $like->save();
    }
    return null;
}
```

P.S:
I'm new to phpstorm and laravel, if you know a good way to debug/log/watch variable values like in eclipse, that would be appreciated.

Comment: open the network tab in dev tools and click on the request so we can see what the actual error is

Answer (score 1):

from what I see the ajax request is using a wrong url it's requesting `localhost/public/likes` instead of `localhost/your_project/public/like`

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'like',
    data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
})
```

should work... or

```
<script>
    var urlLike = '{{ URL::to('like') }}';
</script>
```

not sure why `route()` is not working though